# How to design the max function for integers using only additions and multiplications?

Tags: functions, algorithms, arithmetic-functions

I want to design a function which outputs the maximum value between two integers, something like this 
$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
  1, & \text{if } x > y, \\
  0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$
, using only additions, substractions and multiplications.

I would like to have a single equation $f(x,y) = x *y *x ..$ where $*$ maybe any operation from the ones mentioned above, if necessary division can be used too but preferably not.

I can restrict the operation to a finite algebraic field $Z_t$.

For equality comparison, I can define the function
$EQU(x,y) = \begin{cases}
  1, & \text{if } x == y, \\
  0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$

If $t$ is prime, the equality comparison can be computed like this $EQU(x,y)=1-(x-y)^\phi$, where the [Euler totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function) $\phi(t)=t-1$, because $t$ is prime. Now, I am asking if something similar could be done for greater than comparison.

I need these comparison functions for a [homomorphic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption) application where functions are computed as arithmetic circuits.

Comment: Given that you have accepted an answer that doesn't meet your stated requirements, it is rather unclear what you were actually asking for.

Comment: EQU does not seem to work as advertised...

Comment: Yes, it doesn't. I replaced t from the exponent with phi(t)=t-1 and if t is prime the equation holds.

Answer (score 4):

A function defined using only addition, subtraction and multiplication is a [polynomial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial). The function $\max(x, y)$ is not a polynomial function. To see this, note that if $\max(x, y)$ were a polynomial, then the function $g$ defined by $g(x)= \max(x, 0)$ would be a non-zero polynomial function with infinitely many roots.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}(x+y+\mid x-y \mid)$$

Answer (score 1):

$\max\{a,b\}=\frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}$, $\min\{a,b\}=\frac{a+b-|a-b|}{2}$